# Need help reshaping dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a datset that looks like this:

```
Name. Position number.student? Married?

Bob. 0001. YES. NO.
Susan. 0002. YES. YES.
Mark. 0003. NO.NO
Becky.0004.NO.YES
Billy.0005.YES.YES
```

I need it to look like this:

```
Bob. 0001. YES. NO.
Susan. 0002. YES. NO.
Susan.0002.NO.YES
Mark. 0003. NO.NO
Becky.0004.NO.YES
Billy.0005.YES.NO
Billy.0005.NO.YES
```

In other words, I have multiple column headers with "Yes" and "No" as values. I need a row for each "Yes" assignment and each person has whatever necessary amount of rows depending upon how many "Yes" values they have.

How can I accomplish this in R?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to get the data in long format, leep only `"YES"` rows, create a sequence column for each `Name` and get the data in wide format filling empty values with `"NO"`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = student:Married) %>%
  filter(value == 'YES') %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fill = "NO") %>%
  select(-row)


#  Name  Positionnumber student Married
#  <chr>          <int> <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Bob                1 YES     NO     
#2 Susan              2 YES     NO     
#3 Susan              2 NO      YES    
#4 Becky              4 NO      YES    
#5 Billy              5 YES     NO     
#6 Billy              5 NO      YES
```

This however removes values where `Name` has both `"NO"`s, here is a an slight variation suggested by @Walker Harrison.

```
df %>%   
  pivot_longer(cols = student:Married) %>%   
  arrange(Name, name) %>%   
  group_by(Name) %>%   
  filter(value == 'YES' | (name == "student" & 
         value == 'NO' & lag(value) == 'NO')) %>%   
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%   
  pivot_wider(values_fill = "NO") %>%   
  select(-row)


# Name  Positionnumber Married student
#  <chr>          <int> <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Becky              4 YES     NO     
#2 Billy              5 YES     NO     
#3 Billy              5 NO      YES    
#4 Bob                1 NO      YES    
#5 Mark               3 NO      NO     
#6 Susan              2 YES     NO     
#7 Susan              2 NO      YES
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Bob", "Susan", "Mark", "Becky", "Billy"
), Positionnumber = 1:5, student = c("YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", 
"YES"), Married = c("NO", "YES", "NO", "YES", "YES")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I think you lost Mark in there somewhere -- just need to add one other condition to the filter to capture when both are 'NO'. Something like `df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = student:Married) %>%
  arrange(Name, name) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(value == 'YES' | (name == "student" & value == 'NO' & lag(value) == 'NO')) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fill = "NO") %>%
  select(-row)`

Comment: @WalkerHarrison Thanks,  I updated the answer with your suggestion.